# can't unfollow a post

Tags: support, bug, following-posts

I'm following [this question](//puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/123158). When I click "Following" to unfollow it, I get a notification that I'm no longer following it. But that's a lie: I still get notifications from it, and if I reload the page it again says "Following". (I tried both in Safari on iOS and in Chrome on MacOS.)

Comment: No longer happening, apparently.

Comment: Strange. Did you manage to work out why?

Comment: @Stiv I did not